# Angular browser animations fps drop diagnosis

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, firefox

I'm using Angular 5 with the material module to create form modals using MatDialogModule and MatInputModule. It works good, however, I'm facing a little performance issue with Firefox and Chrome:

When the modal contain only 1 input, there's no performance issues, but when it contains 10 inputs, the fps drops when I open the dialog (in Chrome), and when I close the dialog (in Firefox).

So, I used the developer console to debug this problem but I can't figure out any information that is helpful. Here's a screenshot from the develop console:

[image: Angular Browser animations fps drop]

As you can see, in the focused part, it's when I close the dialog (click outside of the modal). Is there a way to debug that behavior?

Comment: Did you find a way to mitigate this frame drop?

Comment: The only solution I found is to use NoopBrowserAnimations (disable animations).